# Setting the ID of NotificationCompat.Builder java android

Tags: android, alarm

I am currently creating an alert with the following code:

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder getChannelNotification(AbstractEvent event) {
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("id",event.getId());

    PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID)
            .setContentTitle(event.getTitle())
            .setContentText("event begins in: " + event.getStartTime)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android)
            .setShortcutId("1")
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", actionIntent)
}
```

This created the alert fine, but I am atempting to then dismiss the alert when I press the "Dismiss" button.

I am trying to do this in another class by using:

```
NotificationManager manager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
manager.cancel(id);
```

This would be fine, However I cannot seem to set the ID of the alarm I have just made.

How can I set/access the ID of the alarm I have just made?

Comment: you want to clear notification on notificationbar when click on notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create the id manually and set it with the notification and store it in a `sharedPreferences`

```
NOTIFICATION_ID = notificationPreferences.getInt("notifnumber",0);
```

as soon as you notify , you increment the value and store it

```
manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
editor.putInt("notifnumber", NOTIFICATION_ID + 1);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: where you create your notification (class , activity , ...)